# Joining two tables in spark that are present in hive

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have written the Java program in eclipse  to join two tables in spark ,but I am getting a error near `package` 
Here is the below error

> The type scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required .class files

This is the program I have wrote

```
package joins;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

public class Spark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
        SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
        HiveContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);
        sqlContext.sql(" use myown ");
        DataFrame table_01 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM customer");
        table_01.saveAsTable("spark_table_01");
        sqlContext.cacheTable("spark_table_01");
        DataFrame table_02 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM account");
        table_02.saveAsTable("spark_table_02");
        sqlContext.cacheTable("spark_table_02");
        DataFrame table_join = sqlContext.sql(" SELECT a.* FROM  customer a join account b on a.ssn=b.ssn ");
        table_join.insertInto("customeraccount");
        sqlContext.uncacheTable("spark_table_01");
        sqlContext.uncacheTable("spark_table_02");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using spark 1.3.0

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are missing the scala reflect jar file in your app. Download scala-reflect.jar, put it in the classpath and recompile.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, I solved this problem by adding scala-reflect-2.11.8.jar as an external jar file. The jar file can be found in "jars" folder of your Spark directory. I am using Spark 2.1.0